# Is the db in $this->db->last_insert() the class or the constant?

Tags: database, codeigniter

Since I am using 2 databases I have 2 separate config setups in config/database.php and load them in the Model's constructor with

```
$this->DB1 = $this->load->database('default', TRUE);  
$this->DB2 = $this->load->database('reserve', TRUE);
```

I need to retrieve the id of the last inserted record and have used `$this->db->last_insert();`
and `$this->DB2->last_insert();`
but neither is working.

My insert query works fine and is

```
   $insArray = array(  
    'propNumber' => $prp,  
    'fname' => $fname,  
    'lname' => $lname,  
    'unit' => $unit,  
    'email' => $email,  
    'NOC' => 0  
    );  
    $this->DB2->insert('users', $insArray);  
    $last_id = $this->db->last_insert();  
    $_SESSION['userID'] = $last_id;  
    return 'valid';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

```
$last_id = $this->DB2->mysql_insert_id();
```